# How can I find an x value that satisfies each of the following equations n>1?

Tags: algorithms

How can I find an x (formula) that satisfies all the equations below for every integer n > 1?

```
n = 2 => 2 + x = 3
n = 3 => 3 + x = 3
n = 4 => 4 + x = 6
n = 5 => 5 + x = 6
n = 6 => 6 + x = 9
n = 7 => 7 + x = 9
n = 8 => 8 + x = 12
n = 9 => 9 + x = 12
n = 10 => 10 + x = 15
n = 11 => 11 + x = 15
…
```

Sorry if this sounds primitive, I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Can you explain the question in more detail, please? Also, you should use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: Are you generating a sequence x(2), x(3), x(4), ..? If so, you will need more terms for people to see the pattern you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `x = 3*floor(n/2) - n`

---

#### How to solve:

- What stands out first is the sequence (3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9) on the right.
- These are all multiples of 3, so loosely speaking this is 3*(1,1,2,2,3,3).
- The sequence (1,1,2,2,3,3) is generated from `floor(n/2)` for n=2,3,4,5,6,7.
- Putting these together gives `n + x = 3*floor(n/2)` from which the answer directly follows.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with even $n$, your formula is $n+x=3\frac{n}{2}$. For odd $n$, the left side is the same, the right side is the same as the previous even integer. You can write this as $$n+x=3\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

Without any floor function, your equations are satisfied for
$$x = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}((-1)^n-1)$$
Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an analytical approach.

I assumed that $n=8\implies8+x=12$ and $n=9\implies 9+x=12$, if so then the general term of your sequence is,

$n=2k\implies 2k+x=3k$

$n=2k+1\implies2k+1+x=3k$ for all $k=1,2,3...$